# Uncompress / process big file gz stored in Oracle folder

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-package

Uncompress big file in Oracle 11

Hi Guys,
I have one big (around 4gb) zipped file (gz) stored in an Oracle folder. The file contains some data that have to be uploaded in a table. The unzipped file is around 50gb.

I cannot use the preprocessor option in the external table definition.

I tried to uncompress it and store the data in a table with a BLOB field, unfortunately it took 5 hours and it seems that something went wrong.

```sql
create table test_table as
select UTL_COMPRESS.LZ_UNCOMPRESS(a.FILEDATA)   AS UNCOMPRESSED_FILE
from dbfs_content a
where
pathname = 'file.txt.gz';
```

Any idea on how to make it faster?

Thanks.
Marco